# Spatial sorting using Hilbert Curve in custom function in QGIS results in unpacking error

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-custom-function

I am trying to implement spatial sorting using a Hilbert Curve. I have taken the code for calculating the Hilbert Curve distance from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_curve and converted it to a custom (python) function for QGIS resulting in the following:

```
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *

#rotate/flip a quadrant appropriately
def rot(n, x, y, rx, ry):
    if ry == 0:
        if rx == 1:
            x = n-1 - x
            y = n-1 - y
        #Swap x and y
        t = x
        x = y
        y = t

@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Custom')
#convert (x,y) to d
def xy2d(n, x, y, feature, parent):
    """
    Calculates Hilbert distance (d). Takes three arguments:
    <ol>
        <li>n = number of grid divisions
        <li>x = x coordinate of feature
        <li>y = y coordinate of feature
    </ol>
    """
    rx, ry, s, d = 0
    while (s == n/2) and (s > 0):
        rx = (x & s) > 0
        ry = (y & s) > 0
        d += s * s * ((3 * rx) ^ ry)
        rot(n, x, y, rx, ry)
        s /= 2
    return d
```

However, I get the following error `Eval Error: cannot unpack non-iterable int object`. I am unsure as to why it should be trying to unpack `d`? This should just be a single dimension value.

Comment: Check this string `rx, ry, s, d = 0` it cause the error, should probably be `rx, ry, s, d = 0, 0, 0, 0`

Comment: Also do not forget about the [hilbertcurve](https://pypi.org/project/hilbertcurve/) package